# How to deploy website on live server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, deployment, web

I have created a website on angularJS. I have local server running using nodeJS. Can anyone please tell me the further process to deploy the website.

Answer (score 2):

Your local server is probably only for development purposes.

You can deploy it as usual application. All you need is web server. The most common selection is Apache, nginx or IIS. You can set up one of these on your own (on your own computer/VPS etc.) or use web hosting (just google it...).

Selecting correct solution depends on budget, needed support and number of users. I assume that usual "cheap web hosting" is the best for you.